# check holiday or not from online Calendar or server with C# ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, calendar

I have a Date which get from Database.
I want to check that Date is Holiday or not in Japanese Calendar from online or server.
There are lots of Holiday type in Japan.

---

[Solved] 
I created Isholiday function and used `wc.OpenRead("http://s-proj.com/utils/checkHoliday.php?kind=h&date=" + date)` to check my selected date is holiday or not from online directly.

Comment: Sorry, this is way to broad a question. Try and find the service you require to look up holidays, then try and call that service. If you have specific problems in any of those steps, ask questions about that. It is off topic to suggest services.

Comment: You need a database table to store Japan-specific holidays such like GW or Tenno's birthday. Then query the table contents & check with current date in server-side (without any sample code it's too broad to reproduce).

Comment: I created Isholiday function and used "http://s-proj.com/utils/checkHoliday.php?kind=h&date=" + date)) to check my selected date is holiday or not from online directly.. Thank you soo much Everyone...

Comment: Since you solved it, post as an answer, not as an edit to your question.

Comment: There is no Answer Question button for me in that question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try [Holiday API](https://holidayapi.com/) , i haven't used it myself but a quick look at documentation reveals that you can  make a GET request and they'll return a JSON response similar to :

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "holidays": [{
    "name": "Independence Day",
    "date": "2015-07-04"
    "observed": "2015-07-03"
    "public": true,
  }]
}
```

As pointed in comments above your question doesn't contain any code samples and is too broad to answer.

Hope this helps !